# How to get results from a completed process instance in Flowable?

Tags: flowable

I have a simple Service task that sets a variable "foo" to "bar".
When a process contains just that one task, and I initiate it using "runtime/process-instances", I can see variable "foo" in the response.
When I add a user task before the service task, and finish the task using action: complete on "runtime/tasks", I just get a 200 result code.
How do I get the resulting variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flowable has 2 sets of services

- `RuntimeService` - which provides information for the runtime data.
- `HistoryService` - which provides information for all the available data (runtime and completed)

In order to access completed tasks / processes you'll need to use the history service. Those endpoints are under `/history`